# How is This Diff Interpreted?

Tags: bash

Can someone explain how the diff would get to "Pass" or not. I'm a bit lost on how this logic is being processed in bash. It looks like that actual diff data and error are going to /dev/null and return codes are being used. But not quite sure. Thanks.

```
description="Ensure events that modify user/group information are collected"

## Tests Start ##
search_term="identity"
expected='-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity\n
    -w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity\n
    -w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity\n
    -w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity\n
    -w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity'
     
diff <(echo -e $expected | sed 's/^\s*//') <(auditctl -l | grep $search_term) &>/dev/null && result="Pass"
```

Comment: `diff <(echo foo) <(echo bar) &>/dev/null && echo "same?"`

Comment: `diff <(echo foo) <(echo foo) &>/dev/null && echo "same?"`

Comment: Ah that helps. Got it thanks.